# Without marking transaction demarcation, just loading an entity through session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

Hibernate:

What happens(what is wrong) if I load an entity saying session.load() and close the session **without beginning a transaction & comitting it**

I gone through various sites, but couldn't find any good explanation.

Comment: I think its a valid question. Instead of voting it down, kindly answer it or correct me if anything goes wrong

Comment: one of the link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

Comment: Is it right to load a persisted entity from session without beginning a transaction(session.beginTransaction). Will that return jdbc connection to its pool after i close session. Note: on transaction.commit() the jdbc connection is returned to its pool. ALSO, can we keep an open session (transaction committed) to help in view-Lazy loading

Comment: session.load() returns the entity from cache if present (then you can use it even after session.close()) or returns a lazyloading proxy (then you will get lazyloadexception after session.close())

Comment: @krishna have a look at the answer comment/upvote/accept if it was helpfult.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right to load a persisted entity from session without beginning a transaction(session.beginTransaction)

Yes. It is ok, but when you fetch data from DB, there might be occasions when hibernate has to fire an update query to flush the dirt data. So, it preferred to run all the DB related activities inside a transaction.

Follow the bellow steps when using the transactions,

1. Start the transaction.
2. Do your DB activities (select/update).
3. Close your transaction.

> Can we keep an open session (transaction committed) to help in view-Lazy loading?

You can do that, but it is not a good approach. If the number of concurrent users are more there will be severe performance issues.